# How do I get the row index/number for a table in xpath?

Tags: xpath

How would I build an xpath that tells me 'Get me the row number inside a table with a cell that has  in it?' Example from W3 schools: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro.

```
<table>
  <t
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this case, if I were to ask 'Get me the row number that has 'Island Trading' in it, I expect to get 4 or 5 depending on if the index starts from zero. I've gotten as far as `//*[contains(text(),'Island')]` with my experimentation, not sure what to do next.

Comment: always tell us the XPath version. Because XPath has 1.0, 2.0 and 3.1 in use.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know @EricChow. I need to ask an external service to find out. I take your point though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI... Selenium WebDriver uses XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you there:

```
count(//tr[td[.='Island Trading']]/preceding-sibling::*)+1
```

or drop the `+1` at the end to count from 0.

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 2.0, you can use `index-of` function. The following example uses `lxml` and `elementpath`.

```py
s="""
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

"""

from lxml import etree
import elementpath
table = etree.XML(s)
index = elementpath.select(table, "index-of(tr, ./tr[td[contains(text(), 'Island')]])")
print(index)
```

The result is 5.

Comment: Turned out that I had to use the other solution, but I will definitely refer to this one if I use XPath 2.0.